# Bootstrap grid with different number of elements per column depending on screen size

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a bootstrap grid to display picture thumbnails, where the number of thumbnails displayed depends on the number of matches to a user's search criteria. I am displaying a different number of thumbnails per row depending on the screen's size, defined as:

```
 <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
```

I then use the following PHP construct to create new row div elements:

```
<?php

                    for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($products); $i++):

                        if ($i % 3 == 0) {

                            if ($i > 0)
                                echo "</div>";

                            echo "<div class=\"row\">";

                        }

                        $product = $products[$i];

                        ?>
```

This works well for -md and -lg but obviously not for -sm and -xs for which I'd need `i%2` and `i%1`. Anybody knows some way I can retrieve from PHP the column size that boostrap is using?

Comment: Bootstrap is responsive, you don't need to know the column size. See: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid Resize your browser window and watch what happens to the examples.

Comment: Hi @KIKOSoftware, thanks for your reply. Thing is I still want to have control over my rows, that is, to only have a certain number of thumbnails per row. (Eg: 3 or 4) When I resize my browser elements are indeed stacked, but if I have say 3 elements per row then this will result in a row with 2 elements with underneath a row with 1 element with underneath a row with 2 elements... Hope this makes sense?

Comment: Yes, it makes sense. A little secret: Simply put as many columns in a row as you need. This can be more than 12, but Bootstrap will always wrap after 12. In your case one row with all the tumbnails will do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bootstrap [allows you to use only one row](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-wrapping) with a large number of cells inside.

> If more than 12 columns are placed within a single row, each group of extra columns will, as one unit, wrap onto a new line.

For example:

```css
.photoes img {
  height: auto;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row photoes">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3"><img src="//placehold.it/900x300/c69/?text=Photo" alt=""></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3"><img src="//placehold.it/900x300/9c6/?text=Photo" alt=""></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3"><img src="//placehold.it/900x300/69c/?text=Photo" alt=""></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3"><img src="//placehold.it/900x300/6c9/?text=Photo" alt=""></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3"><img src="//placehold.it/900x300/96c/?text=Photo" alt=""></div>
    
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3"><img src="//placehold.it/900x300/c69/?text=Photo" alt=""></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3"><img src="//placehold.it/900x300/9c6/?text=Photo" alt=""></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3"><img src="//placehold.it/900x300/69c/?text=Photo" alt=""></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3"><img src="//placehold.it/900x300/6c9/?text=Photo" alt=""></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3"><img src="//placehold.it/900x300/96c/?text=Photo" alt=""></div>
    
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3"><img src="//placehold.it/900x300/c69/?text=Photo" alt=""></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3"><img src="//placehold.it/900x300/9c6/?text=Photo" alt=""></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3"><img src="//placehold.it/900x300/69c/?text=Photo" alt=""></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3"><img src="//placehold.it/900x300/6c9/?text=Photo" alt=""></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3"><img src="//placehold.it/900x300/96c/?text=Photo" alt=""></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Mrd I am glad to be helpful. Here is a link to documentation about [Column wrapping](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-wrapping).